# Select distinct values from 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, distinct

I want to select distinct values from only one column (the BoekingPlaatsId column) with this query:

```
SELECT MAX(BoekingPlaatsId), BewonerId, Naam, VoorNaam
FROM table
GROUP BY BewonerId, Naam, VoorNaam
```

How do I do that in SQL Server?

Comment: "I want to select **distinct** values [...]". Awesome how close one can be to the answer without knowing it :)

Answer (score 23):

`DISTINCT` should work if you just want the user names:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BewonerId, Naam, Voornaam
FROM TBL
```

but if you need the minimum ID values, group by the names...

```
SELECT MIN(BoekingPlaatsId), MIN(BewonerId), Naam, Voornaam
FROM TBL
GROUP BY Naam, Voornaam
```

Comment: Grouping by everything is fine for a small table but it sucks for a large table.

Answer (score 8):

I think you should be able to use

```
SELECT DISTINCT BewonerId, Naam, VoorNaam
```

You can't add `BoekingPlaatsId`, because:

- `DISTINCT` looks for unique **rows**
- You need to specify what `BoekingPlaatsId` value you want
  (In case of Jan Janssens, do you want BoekingPlaatsId 1 or 2?)

What also works is this:

```
SELECT MAX(BoekingPlaatsId), BewonerId, Naam, VoorNaam
FROM ...
GROUP BY BewonerId, Naam, VoorNaam
```

Comment: Jup dude! your second query worked like a charm! this is my first time on these forums but you guys convinced me well! I'll be surfing around here again! I think I'll be learning a lot from you guys! Problem solved ;)

Answer (score 6):

I don't do alot of this so i'm not 100% certain of the syntax so you may need to tweak it slightly, google rank over and partition. Try this...

```
SELECT 
    *,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Naam  order by Naam ) as Rank
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE 
    Rank = 1
```

This is overkill for a 4 column table, but if you have a fairly denormalised table with alot of columns, this approach is invaluable for select distinct on 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

just group By those 2 columns

```
  Select Min(BoekingPlaatsId), Min(bewonerId), naam, voornaam
  from table
  group By naam, voornaam
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Naam, Voornaam, min(BewonerId), min(BoekingPlaatsId) from tableName
group by Naam, Voornaam
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
select distinct column1 from table1 where column2 = (select distinct column2 from table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can select from a table with only unique values for your column:

```
CREATE VIEW [yourSchema].[v_ViewOfYourTable] AS
WITH DistinctBoekingPlaats AS
(
    SELECT [BewonerId], 
           [Naam],
           [VoorNaam],
           [BoekingPlaatsId],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [BoekingPlaatsId] ORDER BY DESC) AS 'RowNum'
    FROM [yourSchema].[v_ViewOfYourTable]
)
SELECT * 
FROM DistinctProfileNames
WHERE RowNum = 1
--if you would like to apply group by you can do it in this bottom select clause but you don't need it to gather distinct values
```

You don't need group by to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and for me the solution was using the **GROUP BY** clause.
So basically, I grouped all the blogs with same title as one group.

Syntax:

```
SELECT post_title, post_link
FROM blogs
WHERE [ conditions ]
GROUP BY post_title
ORDER BY post_title;
```

Maybe you are grouping multiple columns

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you want something like

```
select distinct(BewonerId), Naam, Voornaam from table_name
```

Comment: This code will still run; it's just not a solution. SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c is the same as SELECT DISTINCT(a), b, c. DISTINCT is not a function call; it's a query option.