# MySQL: Ignore a selected column when using DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, distinct

Let's say:

1. I want to query colA, colB and colC in my table.
2. I want to see DISTINCT values but I don't want colA to be a criteria for distinction.
3. Omitting colA isn't an option.

What's the best way to structure that query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918556/sql-select-distinct-values-from-1-column

Possible duplicate.

Answer (score 14):

There are two cases here. Let's say you have the data

```
A  B  C   (columns)
a  b  c1
a  b  c2
```

Taking distinct values of A, B gives just one result (a,b), with two values for column C.
So the question is do you want to see all values of C or just one value for each distinct value of columns A and B?

If you want to see just one value of C, then you can write

```
SELECT A, B, MAX(C) FROM YourTable
  GROUP BY A, B
```

On the other hand, if you want to see all values for C then

```
SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C FROM YourTable WHERE ROW(A,B) IN 
  (SELECT A, B FROM YourTable
     GROUP BY A, B)
```

gives you that. This last alternative is needed if there are other columns in the table.

Comment: The first option looks good, but isn't the second one equivalent to SELECT DISTINCT A,B,C ?

Comment: @Keith - If there are no other columns, then it is the same, but as the answer says "This last alternative is needed if there are other columns in the table."

Comment: I don't understand how SELECT DISTINCT A,B,C doesn't work if there are extra columns.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the syntax for a temporary table, so pseudocode if you please =)

```
Select Distinct ColB, ColC into @Temp
From SomeTable
Where (predicates)

Select ColA, ColB, ColC
From SomeTable
Inner Join @Temp on (SomeTable.ColB = @Temp.ColB and SomeTable.ColC = @Temp.ColC)
Where (predicates)   /* Added for comments */
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wouldn't that just produce a copy of SomeTable?  The inner join will match exactly one row in @Temp.

Comment: The Inner Join will match all rows that contain both column values, and no others.

Comment: Yes, but all rows in SomeTable (matching the predicate, if there is one) have their (ColB, ColC) pairs in the @Temp table.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  You mean when a paticular ColA value might not be wanted?
Will add a predicate to second select.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean.  I mean even without predicates in both statements, you aren't doing what the OP wanted.  The inner join with @Temp is pointless - you are finding the matching entry in @Temp for each entry in SomeTable.  There will always be exactly one such row.  As such, your join is not accomplishing anything - you are just adding some extra redundant columns to SomeTable and then throwing them away.

Answer (score -1):

try below structure

```
Select cola, colb, colc, CONCAT(convert(cola,char),convert(row_number(), char)
```

Hope This helps

Comment: This isn't valid SQL syntax.