# select unique rows according to a specified column

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table containing duplicates according to specified column;`personid` in this case, how to select unique rows (excluding column `date`) ?

```
date       |personid  |amount  |category |location
23/02/2017 |frank     |2344.00 |productA |uk
23/02/2017 |claire    |4443.23 |productB |usa
24/02/2017 |frank     |2344.00 |productA |uk
```

select unique rows, excluding `date` column:

```
personid  |amount  |category |location
frank     |2344.00 |productA |uk
claire    |4443.23 |productB |usa
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917558/mysql-ignore-a-selected-column-when-using-distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
select distinct personid,amount,category,location from table
```

OR

```
select personid, amount, category, location FROM table group by  personid, amount, category, location
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT personid, amount, category, location
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY personid, amount, category, location
```

Or `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT personid, amount, category, location
FROM yourTable
```

You might find it useful to know that `DISTINCT` is often implemented under the hood using `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

use distinct like this

```
Select distinct personid,amount,category,location from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t0.*
FROM table AS t0
LEFT JOIN table AS t1 
    ON t0.personid=t1.personid 
    AND t0.amount=t1.amount 
    AND t1.date>t0.date 
    AND t1.category=t0.category 
    AND t1.location= t0.location
WHERE t1.col1 IS NULL;
```