# Have a subquery return a row instead of a column

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    [Address]=e.Address, 
    [LastEmail] = 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 [Email] 
        FROM Email innerE 
        WHERE e.UserID = innerE.UserID 
        AND innerE.Contact = @emailId
        AND (IsSent is null OR isSent = 0)
        ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
    )

FROM Emails e
```

This works fine, but now, I realized i'd like to get the entire row containing that lastemail column, if this is possible, any ideas on how it could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
;WITH LastEmails
AS
(
   SELECT *, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Timestamp DESC) rownum
   FROM Emails
   WHERE Contact = @emailId
     AND (IsSent is null OR isSent = 0)
)
SELECT * FROM LastEmails
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Comment: I used a combination of this answer and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1918586/27483 to provide what I needed. Instead of row_number(), I used rank(), too.

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports it you can use [APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (which I think it does as it looks like SQL-Server Syntax)

```
SELECT  [Address]=e.Address, 
        [LastEmail] = ie.Email
FROM    Emails e
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 *
            FROM    Email innerE 
            WHERE   e.UserID = innerE.UserID 
            AND     innerE.Contact = @emailId
            AND     (IsSent is null OR isSent = 0)
            ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
        ) ie
```

This works similar a correlated subquery but allows mulitple rows and multiple columns.