# Sql do not show record with the same name

Tags: sql, database

I have a table with this data:

```
ID  |  NAME
----------------    
1      Airplane
2      Bus
3      Airplane
4      Train
5      Train
```

I want to show only the record with the same "name", like

- Airplane
- Bus
- Train

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want show only the  `name` column and unique data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Select distinct values from 1 column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918556/sql-select-distinct-values-from-1-column)

Comment: What database?  MySQL, SQL Server?  Oracle? Postgresql?  something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the keyword `distinct` for it. The result is a result set with no duplicates.

```
SELECT distinct Name FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

This sentence is confusing:

> I want to not show only the record with the same "name", like

Do you mean that you want to remove duplicates?
Or do you mean that duplicated rows should be excluded?

Both are very easy in SQL - the below code is from SQL Server.

```
declare @t table(id int, name nvarchar(100));
insert into @t values(1,'Airplane')
insert into @t values(2,'Bus')
insert into @t values(3,'Airplane')
insert into @t values(4,'Train')
insert into @t values(5,'Train')

--remove duplicates
select distinct name from @t

--only show rows that are *not* duplicated
select name from @t group by name having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: But how to show it??? My table has 3 columns and i want to use "distinct" only on "name" column..
So Value("id") and Value("surname") - the name of the other columns - don't works!

Comment: @Pelandro can you provide some sample input & output?  If the "other columns" are different across these rows, which one should we choose to output?

Comment: I've find the solution: 2 loop one inside the other to show all the record i need. The first loop with DISTINCT and the second none! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Here is also one easy way

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)

FROM <table_name>

GROUP BY name

HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```